# Currency conversion with easymoney and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, currency

I am trying to convert values with different currency to "USD" currency. I tried `easymoney` and `CurrencyConvertor` packages but those do not seem to work with dataframe python.

It seems working if I do conversion row by row using `iloc` but that is taking an awful lot of time.

```py
from easymoney.money import EasyPeasy
ep = EasyPeasy()
ep.currency_converter(df_train['goal'], from_currency=df_train['currency'], to_currency="USD")
```

```
Error:  
TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for processing by rows:

```
from easymoney.money import EasyPeasy 
ep = EasyPeasy() 
df_train['converted'] = df_train.apply(lambda x: ep.currency_converter(x['goal'], from_currency=x['currency'], to_currency="USD"), axis=1)
```

Comment: How do you deal with `null` values? I keep getting the error `'cannot convert float NaN to integer'`

Comment: @kevinaskevin - There are 2 ways generally - replace `NaN`s or `None`s to some integer by `fillna()` or remove rows by `dropna`

Comment: this runs very slow for a dataframe with 1m rows+. Why is that?

Comment: @Snow - Problem is custom function, main resaon is solution is not vectorized.