# Converting USD -> EUR in large pandas database with varying dates

Tags: python, pandas, currency

I'm trying to convert a column in my Pandas DataFrame from USD to EUR. Each entry has a different date so needs a different conversion rate. The problem is that the DataFrame contains over 200 million rows so it should be as efficient as possible. Does anyone have an idea how to do this efficiently? I tried this, but it seems to be extremely slow:

```
    from easymoney.money import EasyPeasy
    ep = EasyPeasy()
    df['money_eur'] = df.apply(lambda x: ep.currency_converter(x['money_usd'], 'USD', 'EUR', date=x['date'].strftime('%d/%m/%Y')), axis=1)
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44618142/currency-conversion-in-pandas

Comment: Yes it is the method I use above which is quite slow...

Comment: `x['date'].strftime('%d/%m/%Y')` you can do as a column operation before the apply, that might shave off some time. Also, have a look at the tqdm package: https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/#pandas-integration which will give you a progress bar during the apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution! Precompute a database with all exchange rates for each day. Use a left merge for the df and the exchange rates df. Now the USD column can be easily used.

```
df = df.merge(exchangeRatesCurrencies, how='left', left_on='date_days', right_on='date_exchange')
df['money_eur'] = df['money_usd'] / df['USD']
```

Comment: did you found the solution for this conversion ?